# Can't access a control in a widget from another widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have this widget in Qt:

```
"connecttoserver.h"
"connecttoserver.cpp"
"connecttoserver.ui"
```

and this one:

```
"mainwindow.h"
"mainwindow.cpp"
"mainwindow.ui"
```

How can I access the "connectToserver" elements from the "mainwindow" widget?

I've tried doing this:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnLogin_clicked()
{
    connectToserver ccc;
    ccc.ui.txt_mail_ip.text();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does not work? Do you get any errors? If so, could you edit your post and add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's C++: to access one widget member from another widget, just create a method (or a Qt slot, if you prefer) and invoke it from the other widget. For being accessible, the method (or the slot) mut be public, or otherwise the two classes must be friend.

Comment: thank you! my problem is fixed! i define a method for set and a method for get!